# Profile Inheritage In spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Is it possible to have a profile in spring boot and also another profile that inherits most of the parent values and beans?

For example I have two profiles 
staging and staging-task.
I want staging-task to inherit the database configuration of the staging profile however I want it to override the jpa configuration.

Is profile inheritance available to @Configuration beans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Its possible to have spring profiles in spring boot.
For your problem, put your common database configuration in application.yml(default profile).

And you can override the other properties in application-stage.yml.

Spring will read the properties from application.yml and override from application-stage.yml when active profile is **stage**.

Comment: I see. This is a good feature. Is profile inheritance available to @Configuration beans? Thank you!

Comment: What about more than one level of inheritance? e.g. foo-dev, foo-prod inheriting from foo and bar-dev, bar-prod inheriting from bar

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

The *active* profiles will cause respective `application-$profile.properties` to be read (if they exist) in the order the active profiles are defined. Later read properties override earlier ones. That will give you the means to do smth. like an hierarchy.

#### Long Version

There is no such thing as profile-*inheritance* in spring but it can be mimicked as written in the answer by JRR.

For how it actually works read: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties.

Comment: What's LT;DR???

Comment: @AdrianM. a typo. Fixed it.